# Why am I not getting my json response?

Tags: php, json, forms, smartystreets

Ok, I think this should generate a json response, but nothing is getting printed out. What am I missing? I am trying to have this input sent to with url request, and then get a json response to print.

```
<?php

// Customize this (get ID/token values in your SmartyStreets account)
$authId = urlencode("id");
$authToken = urlencode("id");

// Address input
$input1 = urlencode($_POST["street"]);
$input2 = urlencode($_POST["city"]);
$input3 = urlencode($_POST["state"]);
$input4 = urlencode($_POST["postcode"]);

// Build the URL
$req = "https://api.smartystreets.com/street-address/?street={$input1}&city={$input2}&state={$input3}&postcode={$input4}&auth-id={$authId}&auth-token={$authToken}";

// GET request and turn into associative array
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($req));



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
     <form action="smarty-geocode.php" name="" method="post">
          <input id="addresses" type="hidden" value="">
          Street Address
          <input id="street" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
          <br />
          City
          <input id="city" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
          <br />
          State
          <input id="state" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
          <br />
          Zipcode
          <input id="postcode" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
          <br />
          Country
          <input id="country" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" id="#mySubmitButton" />
     </form>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:40%;top:30px;"></div>
<div>
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: before you ask a question here think twice if it fits the quality standards. How we should help you with this? you cannot expect that I create an account on `smartystreets.com`. So you need to put the response data from that api request into the question.

Comment: At least supply working input values, the req-url these generate and the response on that url. You should also supply the var dump of $result. And some nitpicking, the json_decode you're doing doesn't turn it into an array ;)

Comment: hek2mgl - That's the question I have. I am not sure what to do here to get the response data. I was expecting that It would generate a response it print it through the request variable. However, that isn't happening.

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information for me to debug the output from your URL - however I think you should be able to solve that yourself by adding this to the bottom of your page:-

```
<?php var_dump(file_get_contents($req)); ?>
```

In addition to this, none of your form elements possess a name attribute so nothing is actually being posted to your script. Here is a modified version of your form which includes the name attributes on each field:-

```
     <form action="smarty-geocode.php" name="" method="post">
      <input id="addresses" name="addresses" type="hidden" value="">
      Street Address
      <input id="street" name="street" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
      <br />
      City
      <input id="city" name="city" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
      <br />
      State
      <input id="state" name="state" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
      <br />
      Zipcode
      <input id="postcode" name="postcode" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
      <br />
      Country
      <input id="country" name="country" type="textbox" value="" class="address">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="#mySubmitButton" />
 </form>
```

Hopefully this, combined with your debugging of the output from the file_get_contents command will help you solve the issue you are having. I'm making the assumption that you are replacing these values with a valid authId and authToken from Smarty Streets:-

```
$authId = urlencode("id");
$authToken = urlencode("id");
```